# #import not finding .h file in Xcode (Version 6.3)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am unable import the .h file. The file is shown in the Project Navigator in Xcode.

Actually for adding the Localytics SDK, I dragged the SDK folder to the project navigator & 'Add to Target' checkbox selected.

[image]

Is it required to add the library to the 'Header Search Path' in the 'Build Settings' ? Presently below values are there in my 'Header Search Path'.

```
"$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include"
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
```

Comment: Does `#import "Localytics.h"` work?

Comment: No, that also not working.

Comment: OK so what `-I` options are being passed to the compiler?  You will most likely need to set-up the *Header Search Path*.

Comment: what value I need to add to the 'Header Search Path' in the Build Settings?

Comment: That depends on your project structure.  Every project is different.

Comment: Localytics-iOS-3.2.0 folder is there in the root directory where the .xcodeproj file is present, so what value I can give in the 'Header Search Path' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77797/discussion-between-sinu-varghese-and-trojanfoe).

Comment: Presently these values are there in my Header Search Path. "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include", "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include",  "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-click on the Header Search Paths value to open the window that lets you add a new path.
Open a Finder window and navigate so that you can see the folder that contains Localytics.h.
Drag the folder into the search path window.
Change your import to `#import "Localytics.h"`.

Comment: Will that automatically substitute `$(SRCROOT)` or `$(PROJECT_DIR)` for the project root folder?  If not it means the project must be used in the same directory on all build machines.

Comment: @Phillip Mills, now it is not showing the error in the import line. But when I build the project it is failing with below message.                                                              Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Localytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @trojanfoe - Yes, it uses the macro if the dragged icon is in the project tree.

Comment: That is good to know and easy to get right.  BTW you have a help vampire after you ;-)  Run!

Comment: @trojanfoe - "Help vampire"?

Comment: Yeah the OP now has linker problems and unable to make the leap from *Header Search Path* to *Library Search Path* required to solve it.

Comment: @SinuVarghese - Sounds like you're back to where you were with a previous question.  If you're still using Cocoapods, I don't have an answer.  (Otherwise, check your link command for the right library and path.)

Comment: @PhillipMills I am not using Cocoapods now. I am installing the localytics sdk manually. So please suggest what else I have to give in the link command.

Comment: What are you currently doing to link the Localytics library?

Comment: @PhillipMills- I could resolve the issue by linking 'libLocalytics.a' file inside the library folder.

Answer (score 2):

For all who have not found issue:

Go to Build settings and search for "Framework Search Paths", then remove everything and put ./ and make it recursive (by double-clicking on it)

IMPORTANT - Don't download Parse framework on Windows and then copy to Mac! inside framework there are some links and while copying they get corrupted. Download the framework directly from Mac and when added to xcode make sure it has "Headers" folder under it in XCode frameworks.

I hope it helps some people.

Comment: What has the framework search path got to do with include files?